# Unable to use custom domain with ALB, Route 53 and Cognito

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, amazon-ecs, amazon-route53, aws-application-load-balancer

I have a Flask app running on ECS, it goes through Application Load Balancer and then Cognito for authentication.

If I copy the ALB's DNS everything works but I have to skip the SSL warning message (which is basically what I'm trying to avoid).

I tried getting a domain and routing the app through Route 53, without success. I get a blank page and if I type www.myapp.com/login I get "Required String parameter 'client_id' is not present"

I also get the same behaviour if I try to use Amazon's Cognito domain (myapp.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com)

I've been bumping my head for the last couple days without a clue how to fix this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you all.